# @storybook/addon-controls multiline code whitespace defined as nowrap

Tags: storybook

How i can put multiline code section to storybook controls description column (`argTypes.ARG_NAME.description`)?

It overrides the `whitespace` to `nowrap` of code inside description cell, and css looks like

```
.css-1521b8c code {
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: rgba(51,51,51,0.9);
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

Is here some setting / option exist? Or how i can override this css?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `./storybook/manager-head.html` with some `<style />` section

something like

```
<style>
  pre code {
    whitespace: pre !important; // or use selector inheritance instead of !important
  }
</style>
```